# List of items in a column tabluator

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabulator

I want a list of items in the tabulator in such a way that the sub-items are visible on clicking on that item. There is an onclick function for the column, but can I have on click for each element of the cell?

I want the column to look as follows:

- Item 1

  - sub item 1
  - sub item 2
- Item 2

  - sub item 3
  - sub item 4

The sub-items should be visible on clicking the corresponding Item

Comment: Post the code you have tried and we can help from there.

Comment: Use jquery's toggle function.

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla javascript and css, you can add one event listener to the document that checks if the clicked element is a `li` descended from the intended `ul` if so check for a child `ul` and toggle a class that will hide it like so:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  if (event.target.matches('.collapsable-subs li')) {
    let subList = event.target.querySelector('ul');
    if (subList) {
      subList.classList.toggle('collapsed')
    }
  }

}, false);
```

```css
.collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="collapsable-subs">
  <li>Item 1
    <ul class="collapsed">
      <li>sub item 1</li>
      <li>sub item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul class="collapsed">
      <li>sub item 3</li>
      <li>sub item 4</li>
      <li>sub item 5 with subs
        <ul class="collapsed">
          <li>sub item 1</li>
          <li>sub item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This allows for nesting many levels deep and only affects `ul` descendants of `.collapsable-subs` in case you have other nested `ul`s in the page. You can also have multiple `ul.collapsable-subs` that will all have the same behavior with no additional scripting and no need for `onclick` attributes.

Comment: Yes this functionality in tabulator.

Answer (score 1):

Tabulator comes with built in functionality to handle nested data.

You have the option of [Nested Data Trees](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.4#tree)

or [Nested Tables](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.4#nested-tables)

You could also use [Custom Row Formatters](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.4#row-formatter) to manipulate the rows in any way you see fit

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to copy event method everywhere

```js
function identify() {
    console.log("Element:\n" +
        event.srcElement.outerHTML +
    "\nRow:" +
        event.srcElement.parentElement.outerHTML)
}
function identify2() {
    var me = event.srcElement, me2 = me;
    while((me2 = me2.parentElement) && me2.tagName != "LI");
    console.log("Element:\n" +
        me.outerHTML);
    if(me2) console.log("Parent:\n" + me2.outerHTML);
    else console.log("Parent LI tag not found.");
}
```

```html
<table onclick="identify()">
    <tr>
        <td>00</td>
        <td>01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<ul onclick="identify2()">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the columns with `cellClick` and append child elements. Take a look at below sample column definition.

```
{
      title: "Select",
      field: "select",
      width: 90,
      cellClick: function(e, cell) {
        //cell is the DOM element which is clicked
        //..write logic to append more elements to expand view
      }

}
```

Comment: I want only that Item to expand and show its subitems, cell click will expand all items.

Comment: The code in the link adds a row element, I want to add an element to a particular column under a particular element.

Comment: @al27 - yes you can do that with css

Comment: In the example, I used rowElement. Instead try this `cell.cell.element.append('<span class="expand">Hello World</span>');`

Answer (score 0):

```
Tabulator.prototype.extendModule("format", "formatters", {
            bold: function (cell, formatterParams) {
                return "<strong>" + cell.getValue() + "</strong>"; //make the contents of the cell bold
            },
            uppercase: function (cell, formatterParams) {
                return cell.getValue().toUpperCase(); //make the contents of the cell uppercase
            },
            makelist: function (cell, formatterParams) {
                var des = cell.getValue()
                var table = ""
                des = des.split('/')
                table += '<ul>'
                for (a = 0; a < des.length; a++) {
                    recs = des[a].split(':')
                    recs[0] = recs[0].replace(' ','')
                    table += '<li>' + recs[0]
                    comps = recs[1].split('+')
                    if (comps[0] == '') {
                        break;
                    }
                    table += '<ul>'
                    for (b = 0; b < comps.length; b++) {
                        table += '<li class="comp" hide="no">' + comps[b] + '</li>'
                    }
                    table += '</ul></li>'

                }
                table += '</ul>'
                return table;

            }
        });
        $('#table').on("click",'.comp',function(e){
            if ($(this).attr("hide") == "no"){

            var element = $(this)

            var name = $(this).text()
            var parent_name = $(this).parent().parent().text().split(' ')[0]
            $.ajax({
                url:'/get_sub_items',
                method:'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({name:name, parent_name:parent_name}),
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    list = '<ul>'
                    for(j = 0 ; j < response.length; j++){
                        list += '<li> '+response[j]+'</li>'
                    }
                    list += '</ul>'
                    $(list).appendTo(element)
                }
            })
            $(this).attr("hide", "yes")
            }
            else{
                $(this).children().hide()
                $(this).attr("hide", "no")
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        })
```